# Error: Unable to find column with logical name - Reference Column is not found

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have this entity .

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="ESCALADETALHE")
public class EscalaDiaBean {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "ESCALADETALHE_S01", sequenceName = "ESCALADETALHE_S01")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "ESCALADETALHE_S01")
    @Column(name = "IDPAI", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 9, scale = 0)
    private Integer idDetalhe;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name ="idEscala")
    private EscalaBean escala;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "dia")
    private Calendar dia;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY ,orphanRemoval = true,cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = EscalaDiaBean.class )
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id.escalaDia")
    private List<EscalaDiaDetalheBean> escalaDiaDetalhes;
    //getters , setters, hash and equals
}
```

It has to get the relation OneToMany for the `EscalaDiaDetalheBean` that has a composite key declared in `EscalaDiaDetalhePK` like below:

```
@Embeddable
public class EscalaDiaDetalhePK implements Serializable {


    @ManyToOne()
    public TurmaBean turma;

    @ManyToOne()
    public EscalaDiaBean escalaDia;
    //getters , setters, hash and equals
}
```

So , I have the clild entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEFINICAOESCALA")
@AssociationOverrides(
        value = {
                @AssociationOverride(name = "id.turma", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name ="idTurma")),
                @AssociationOverride(name = "id.escalaDia", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name ="idEscalaDia")),
        }
)
public class EscalaDiaDetalheBean  implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    public EscalaDiaDetalhePK id;


    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public TurnoBean turno;
}
```

What is the correct way to do the relation `EscalaDiaBean` with EscalaDiaDetalheBean?.

Doing of the way described below, I got **Unable to find column with logical name: id.escalaDia in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(ESCALADETALHE) and its related supertables and secondary tables**

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY ,orphanRemoval = true,cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = EscalaDiaBean.class )
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id.escalaDia")
    private List<EscalaDiaDetalheBean> escalaDiaDetalhes;
```

Comment: Here's how you create a bidirectional OneToMany association: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional.

Comment: I have to use the mappedBy? I've already tried @JBNizet

Comment: If the official documentation and the specification tell that you must use mappedBy, then you must use mappedBy, yes. The fact that you still have errors once you have used mappedBy just shows that there are *other* errors, and/or that you used mappedBy incorrectly.

Comment: I got this error : 
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.gapso.sigma.beans.EscalaDiaBean.id.escalaDia in com.gapso.sigma.beans.EscalaDiaBean.escalaDiaDetalhes. the mapped by does not see the id.escalaDia

Comment: So you haven't read the documentation correctly. Let's say you have a Car entity, with a OneToMany property named "passengers". In the Passenger entity, you have a ManyToOne propery named "car". The mappedBy attribute must be inside the OneToMany annotation, and must contain the name of the property annotated with the matching ManyToOne, i.e. "car". The targetEntity of the OneToMany entity, in that previous example, is Passenger, not Car. Specifying it is useless, since Hibernate knows that the property is of type Set<Passenger>. Why are you setting `targetEntity = EscalaDiaBean.class`?

Comment: I think you didn't understood my problem. Yes I have read the official documentation. I'm using a composite primary key , and the property owner of the relation is in the embeddable class.  This IS NOT a simple relationship , and I'm sure that the specify of targetEntity is not causing the trouble. I just want solve my problem , I don't want to became an expert on hibernate.

Comment: `id.escalaDia` is not a valid column name. It tells you that, so put a valid column name. This is COLUMN, not FIELD.

Comment: And I'm sure specifying an incorrect target entity won't make the mapping right. But I have many years of experience with Hibernate, and apparently you don't. So maybe you could assume that what I say is correct. Remove that incorrect, and useless, targetEntity. Remove that incorrect JoinColumn annotation on escalaDiaDetalhes, too.

Comment: the @JBNizet 's comment make sense